# Tornado's IOLoop.call_later is behaving inexplicably

Tags: python, tornado

From an interpreter session:

```
>>>io_loop.call_later(comments_page_delay, functools.partial(http_client.fetch, "google.com", lambda x: print('kek')))
<tornado.ioloop._Timeout object at 0x7fe9a2427b08>
>>> io_loop.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 755, in start
    raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
>>> io_loop.call_later(comments_page_delay, functools.partial(http_client.fetch, "google.com", lambda x: print('kek')))
<tornado.ioloop._Timeout object at 0x7fe9a0267808>
>>> io_loop.stop()
>>> io_loop.start()
>>> io_loop.start()
kek
kek
kek
```

Here:

```
io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
comments_page_delay = 0.1
```

EDIT:

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.max_clients = max_clients
http_client.request_timeout = request_timeout
```

Problem:

The ioloop doesn't seem to run the call added with call_later. It's running, as evident by the error when I try to do io_loop.start(). To make it actually execute, I have to first stop the loop, then start it *twice*... Very confusing.

I admit it's been a while since I've used Tornado, but this is basically equivalent to other code I had which I know worked.

**EDIT**: The code works correctly on the first run, but not on consecutive runs. At that point the need to run io_loop.start() twice returns

Here's the full code (slightly censored):

```
"""...docstring..."""
import functools

import tornado
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from lxml import html as lh

from config import comments_page_delay, max_clients, request_timeout
from debug import log

AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient")
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.max_clients = max_clients
http_client.request_timeout = request_timeout

io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()

def x(y, proxy):
    """...docstring..."""
    def handle_response(response):
        if response.error:
            log('...message...'
                .format(uid, response.error), 1)
        else:
            print('Worked')
            data = response.body

    comments_url = "...valid url..."

    io_loop.call_later(comments_page_delay, functools.partial(http_client.fetch, comments_url, handle_response,
                                                              proxy_host=proxy['host'], proxy_port=proxy['port']))

x(1, {'host': None, 'port': None})

io_loop.start()
print('ok')
io_loop.stop()
```

I'm running the code in an Emacs python interpreter session, if that is somehow relevant. I'll try in a normal python session in a second.

**EDIT2**: Here's what happens if I run that code in a normal python interpreter:

```
$ python -i fetch.py
Worked


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch.py", line 34, in <module>
    io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 863, in start
    event_pairs = self._impl.poll(poll_timeout)
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> >>> >>> get_user_profile_link(1, {'host': None, 'port': None})
>>> 
>>> 
>>> io_loop.start()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 755, in start
    raise RuntimeError("IOLoop is already running")
RuntimeError: IOLoop is already running
>>> io_loop.stop()
>>> io_loop.start()
>>> io_loop.start()
Worked
```

It appears that io_loop.start() is blocking? I didn't think it was, that might be the issue. I'll have to rethink the architecture of my whole program now.

Comment: What version of python and tornado are you use? Does the ioloop is running in the other thread? call_later is not thread-safe.

Comment: Python 3.6, latest version of Tornado.

Not sure what you mean about thread safety here. I'm not doing anything special with threads.

Comment: From Tornado's docs add_timeout (applies to call_later too) - http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_timeout : Note that it is not safe to call add_timeout from other threads. Instead, you must use add_callback to transfer control to the IOLoop‘s thread, and then call add_timeout from there.

Comment: This is all in the same thread, though. If it wasn't, I would've specified.

Comment: Provide step-by-step example. the simplest test I've run https://pastebin.com/X7cTJX6K hasn't show any problem. I thought about different thread because running ioloop is blocking and the context in the question is unclear.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the code anymore; I've updated the question. I did run code that was almost exactly the code you just posted and it did have the issue, but it's fixed now.

EDIT: scratch this, not fixed.

Comment: `IOLoop.start` is blocking in the way that if the loop is running (until stop) no further code (after/below the start) will be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An uncaught exception (in this case the `KeyboardInterrupt`) leaves the `IOLoop` in an undefined state. It is not possible to restart the `IOLoop` after such an exception has occurred (because it could come at any point and leave the `IOLoop`'s internals inconsistent). In general it's assumed that the process will simply exit after a `KeyboardInterrupt`. It's possible to create a new `IOLoop` and start over with it, but you'll have to be careful to recreate *all* objects that depend on it.

Unfortunately, this means that it's practically difficult to use Tornado with the interactive interpreter. My usual workflow for developing Tornado applications is to run a script with `python -m tornado.autoreload` and let the script re-run from scratch whenever I edit it.